# Contar datas iguais select MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, select

Olá, num banco MySql tenho uma tabela assim:

```js
email | data_envio
  a   |2016-10-01 05:32:57
  b   |2016-10-02 09:36:56
  c   |2016-10-02 08:16:52
  d   |2016-10-03 10:36:51
  e   |2016-10-04 10:36:51
```

Como faço um select que me retorne por exemplo a quantidade de envios no dia 02/10/2016?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma opção é buscar pelos horários entre 00 horas e 23:59:

```
SELECT COUNT(email) AS quantidade
  FROM tabela
 WHERE data_envio BETWEEN '2016-10-02 00:00:00' AND '2016-10-02 23:59:59';
```

Você também pode usar a função `DATE` para converter para `data` ignorando as informações de horário:

```
SELECT DATE(data_envio) as data_envio,
       COUNT(email) AS quantidade
  FROM tabela
 GROUP BY DATE(data_envio)
```

---

> [`GROUP BY Modifiers`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)
>
> The `GROUP BY` clause permits a `WITH ROLLUP` modifier that causes summary output to include extra rows that represent higher-level (that is, super-aggregate) summary operations. `ROLLUP` thus enables you to answer questions at multiple levels of analysis with a single query. For example, `ROLLUP` can be used to provide support for `OLAP (Online Analytical Processing)` operations.
>
> Suppose that a sales table has year, country, product, and profit columns for recording sales profitability:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE sales(
>   year    INT,
>   country VARCHAR(20),
>   product VARCHAR(32),
>   profit  INT
> );
> ```
>
> To summarize table contents per year, use a simple `GROUP BY` like this:
>
> ```
> SELECT year, SUM(profit) AS profit
>   FROM sales
>  GROUP BY year;
>
> +------+--------+
> | year | profit |
> +------+--------+
> | 2000 |   4525 |
> | 2001 |   3010 |
> +------+--------+
> ```

Em tradução livre:

> A cláusula `GROUP BY` permite um modificador`WITH ROLLUP` que faz com que a saída de resumo inclua linhas extras que representam operações de resumo de nível superior (isto é, super agregadas). O `ROLLUP` permite-lhe responder a questões em múltiplos níveis de análise com uma única consulta. Por exemplo, `ROLLUP` pode ser usado para fornecer suporte para operações`OLAP (Online Analytical Processing)`.
>
> Suponha que uma tabela de vendas tenha colunas de ano, país, produto e lucro para registrar a lucratividade das vendas:
>
> ```
> CREATE TABLE sales(
>   year    INT,
>   country VARCHAR(20),
>   product VARCHAR(32),
>   profit  INT
> );
> ```
>
> Para resumir o conteúdo da tabela por ano, use um `GROUP BY` simples assim:
>
> ```
> SELECT year, SUM(profit) AS profit
>   FROM sales
>  GROUP BY year;
>
> +------+--------+
> | year | profit |
> +------+--------+
> | 2000 |   4525 |
> | 2001 |   3010 |
> +------+--------+
> ```